# Using regex in Java to extract string after first comma and before two capital letters and a comma

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working with strings that follow this format:

```
4,Matt, Hopkins,MI,5.75,Wood,33.0,2.25,2.1,2016-09-02,74.25,69.3,8.254125,151.804125
```

and I am trying to use regex to extract all the words and integers as separate strings ( as in MI, Wood, 33.0 and so forth) with one exception: I want to treat the part that follows the first comma as a single string, until we get to the all caps - so the regex would extract this:

```
[4] [Matt, Hopkins] [MI] [5.75] [Wood] and so forth.
```

Note that the name part can have no commas at all i.e. [Hopkins] or more than one i.e. [Matt, Jr., Hopkins]. The all caps field desribes a state and so always follows the same format.

I do not understand Regex well enough to do that - so far I only came up with

```
[a-zA-Z(?:\d*\.)?\d+-]+
```

which handles all fields alright, except the name.

Comment: Looks like CSV data. Why not use a CSV library to correctly parse it into fields (or just `String.split`, if the data never has quotes, newlines etc in it), and then recombine as required?

Comment: @AndyTurner a simple `String.split` wouldn't work 100%, since the example from OP shows `[Matt, Hopkins]` as a single field. Unless they just deal with this case after the split.

Comment: @rgoliveira which is why I say "and then recombine as required".

Comment: @AndyTurner oh, right. Guess I read that too fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like (my Java is a bit rusty and I'm posting this from a phone):

```
String[] values = data.split(",(?! )");
```

Java allows splitting a string on a regex, and this simple specimen uses a negative lookahead to ensure that you're only splitting on CSV commas, rather than the ones in names.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex might just make things harder for yourself here.

This looks like CSV data. You can use a CSV library to correctly parse this into individual fields (*):

```
String[] fields = YourCsvLibrary.parseRow(string);  // or string.split(","), maybe.
```

and then recombine the fields as appropriate. For example, your regex's logic can be expressed via the following code:

```
String[] output = Arrays.copyOfRange(fields, 1, fields.length);
output[0] = fields[0];
output[1] = fields[1] + "," + fields[2];
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CCoGVD)

---

(*) `String.split(",")` might work, provided the field data doesn't contain quotes, commas, newlines, etc.

Comment: That's a cool use of `<kbd>` markdown! I think `fields[1] + "," + fields[2]` is not what OP has in mind, though, because he says "everything till the all-caps string". So if there is an entry that looks like `Matt,J,Hopkins` he's looking to get all three parts into a single string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "so the regex would extract this" in the question shows the same grouping as in the ideone demo.

Comment: OP's regex is not a good one (he says it handles everything except the name) and also it's a wrong tool for the job, as you correctly noted ([now OP has two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)).

Comment: I do not see how this works when the name part has no commas at all, as was specified as being possible by the OP. In that case, when the name is 'Hopkins' alone without a comma, the shown code merges this to 'Hopkins,MI'

Comment: @P.J.Meisch it doesn't. But it's not a hard case to detect: there's one fewer field in the row. So, "recombine as appropriate".